# Cannot select just written word after a white space by selection api

Tags: javascript, selection, textselection

- i'm learned selection api soon and i cannot found a real tutorial who is explain everything about it i checked the MDN tutorial but there's just examples about properties of `window.getSelection()` object but there's something like `document.createRange()` object and also `sel.offsetNode` return an object and i'm really finding some defecaults when working with selection - i was decided to learn it to just create a simple text editor which can highlight text and introduce some suggestions
- nearly i'm success at the first point with 50% i can search for word by match method so when the user write this word it's highlight it but also the problem is that `match` method will execute the code and repeat the text because it already can match it - i thought that the best solution is to get just the word who is wrote like imagine that i have this text `welcome in our page` i thought that if i can get every text who has white space between them that's will be helpful which means if i wrote text get me just this text and when clicking white space start get me the letters of just the new word after space like android keyboard who introduced a new suggestions every time i write new word

> Here's what i tried

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
sel = window.getSelection(),
range = document.createRange();

function move() { 
     range.selectNodeContents(div);
     range.collapse(false);
     sel.removeAllRanges();
     sel.addRange(range);
}

div.addEventListener("keyup", function () { 
    if(this.innerHTML.match(/(keyword)[^\>keyword\<]/ig)) { 
        this.innerHTML = this.innerText.replace(/\</ig, "&lt;").replace(/\>/ig, "&gt;").replace(/keyword/ig, function(word) { 
            let x = "<span style='color: crimson'>"+word.toLowerCase()+"</span>";
            return x
        });
        move()
    }
    
})
```

- also the user inputs can contains some html tags so i replaced them
- also i tried something like `sel.offsetNode.data` but it's get me the whole text of the div
- i need to any help because i'm really confused

Comment: Hey man, I just wanted to say well done on getting this far already --- this is, in my opinion, **the** worst API on the web. It's incredibly confusing to use (I definetly have issues with it) and terribly hard to get to do what you want it to. I know this isn't an answer to your question, but I once wrote a wrapper over this API to make it easier to work with, and it's all quite well commented I think --- maybe taking a look over how that solves some of the problems will lead you in the right direction? You can find it here: https://github.com/oparisblue/selection-utils

Answer (score 0):

## Considerations

- New lines: each browser does this differently. Some wrap the line in a `<div>`, some in a `<p>`, I think IE inserts a `<br>`? Point is, it's different on each browser.
- What if they press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> inside the `keyword` text? Are we going to remove the highlighting?
- Technically the caret (flashing text insertion point) counts as a selection with a size of 0. So when we `removeAllRanges`, that will get moved to the start of the text --- not what we want!
- This is a terrible API.

---

## Game Plan

I'm slightly confused by exactly what you want to have happen, but you mention that you want something kinda like the Android / iOS keyboard autocomplete suggestions. So, what we'll do is just *extract the word which comes before the caret*.

To do this, whenever they type we'll need to:

1. Find the caret position.
2. Find the word that the caret position is inside-of / after in the text.

### Finding the Caret Position

As previously mentioned, the caret is just a range where the start and end positions are the same. So, we can get the first range, check that it's not a selection by checking those numbers are the same, and then get the start offset to get the caret positon:

```js
let caret = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    
if (caret.startOffset == caret.endOffset) {
    console.log(caret.startOffset);
}
```

### Finding the relevant word

If we get the caret's container (not the `<div>` itself, because remember that text with line breaks might in a nested element, etc), then we can find its text content. With that, we can find the character where the caret is at, and then loop backwards until we either find a space or hit the beginning of the element. This will give us the text that we need to select.

```js
let text = caret.startContainer.textContent;
let wordStart = 0;
let wordEnd = caret.startOffset;
for (let i = wordEnd; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (text[i] == " ") {
        wordStart = i;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(text.slice(wordStart, wordEnd));
```

### Putting it all together

```js
let editor = document.getElementById("editor");
let suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");

editor.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    let caret = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    
    // Is it only a caret --- e.g. they have no other text selected
    if (caret.startOffset == caret.endOffset) {
        // Find the start point: work backwards from the caret until
        // we find a space character.
        let text = caret.startContainer.textContent;
        let wordStart = 0;
        let wordEnd = caret.startOffset;
        for (let i = wordEnd; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (text[i] == " ") {
                wordStart = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    
    // Display the word
    suggestions.innerHTML = text.slice(wordStart, wordEnd);
    }
    
});
```

```css
#editor {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

#suggestions {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
Current word: <span id="suggestions"></span>
```